# Prepare Statement Issue sending encrypted information

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

This is my current statement. Everything was working fine until I added the key

Key is just a generated hash for the user to activate the account.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Account (accountUsername,accountPassword,accountEmail,accountActivate,accountKey) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssiss', $username, $newPassword, $email,0,$key,time());
```

When I'm doing this code I'm getting an error.

> Cannot pass parameter 5 by reference

Do you know what could be the issue?

Thanks!

Edit Code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Account (accountUsername,accountPassword,accountEmail,accountActivate,accountKey,accountCreated) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssisi', $username, $newPassword, $email,0,$key,$time);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th5tl.png

Comment: `"0"` needs to be passed as a variable and passing numbers as string shows that you have some serious database issues, as in not properly using the field type MySQL offers you to store your data.

Comment: I can change that but this is not the issue.

Comment: that is exactly THE issue, is not just changing it from `"0"` to `0` it needs to be as a variable aka `$val = 0;` and there is no point using `0` if your database column type is `string` instead of `int` which is what I meant by not using the proper database field type. A good example of it would be using a string to store a date/time field which would make you lose a LOT benefits of using the proper field type `DATETIME`.

Comment: Take a look at the picture I inserted.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `bind_param` that 0 needs to be in a variable since `bind_param` passes by reference.

```
$somevar=0;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Account (accountUsername,accountPassword,accountEmail,accountActivate,accountKey) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssiss', $username, $newPassword, $email,$somevar,$key,$time);
```

Comment: @Jean-Mathieu If you do not understand why this is happening, It's a limitation with the MySQLI API, i'm not sure exactly why it's not aloud, but basically. You can not directly input values into the bind query, alternatives would be to do as @mihai has done, **or** set a default field value in mysql, **or** have non-user input in your insert query (`INSERT INTO account (accusername,another) values (?,0)`)